# Entity Framework Core not working with Windows Authentication

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Whenever I try to connect to the database I get this exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "TrackTvDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-MTHC289\hristo.kolev'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.AsyncQueryMethodProvider.<GetResult>d__16`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ManualTesting.EntryPint.<MainAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at ManualTesting.EntryPint.Main(String[] args)
```

I have SqlServer 2016 and this is a .Net Core application.

Here is the DbContext

```
namespace TrackTv
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    using TrackTv.Models;
    using TrackTv.Models.Joint;

    public class TrackTvDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Network> Networks { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Show> Shows { get; set; }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=TrackTvDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");

            base.OnConfiguring(builder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // ShowsUsers
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsUsers>().HasKey(t => new
                        {
                            t.UserId,
                            t.ShowId
                        });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsUsers>().HasOne(t => t.User).WithMany(user => user.ShowsUsers).HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsUsers>().HasOne(t => t.Show).WithMany(show => show.ShowsUsers).HasForeignKey(t => t.ShowId);

            // ShowsActors
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsActors>().HasKey(t => new
                        {
                            t.ShowId,
                            t.ActorId
                        });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsActors>().HasOne(t => t.Show).WithMany(show => show.ShowsActors).HasForeignKey(t => t.ShowId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsActors>().HasOne(t => t.Actor).WithMany(actor => actor.ShowsActors).HasForeignKey(t => t.ActorId);

            // ShowsGenres
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsGenres>().HasKey(t => new
                        {
                            t.ShowId,
                            t.GenreId
                        });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsGenres>().HasOne(t => t.Show).WithMany(show => show.ShowsGenres).HasForeignKey(t => t.ShowId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowsGenres>().HasOne(t => t.Genre).WithMany(genre => genre.ShowsGenres).HasForeignKey(t => t.GenreId);
        }
    }
}
```

My project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        },
        "TrackTv": "*",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can login with Management Studio like this:
[image]

I have several other working .NET applications that access that instance of SqlServer with EF6.

Answer (score 5):

Can you please try adding Integrated Security attribute in you connection string?

```
 builder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=TrackTvDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=true");
```

Comment: No, `Trusted_Connection=True` does what `Integrated Security=true` does. I have tried that.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
```

Doesn't working for me:

```
Trusted_Connection=True 
Integrated Security=SSPI;
Integrated Security=true
```

But this resolve my problem **TrustServerCertificate=True;**